# Saving ResultSets in away for the future intent to push to a UI on a press of a button?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I am creating a UI in JavaFX with the future intent to display an Image of a book along with it's properties like Title, ISBN etc.

I have an upload function which is working and storing it into a MySQL Database using PreparedStatements.

What I am unsure about is how to retrieve the ResultSets and 1 row of data(Book Properties) into the UI. When pressing a next button, this will then show the next row of data.

I have tried to do this with a two Dimensional ArrayList, but unsure this is the approach to take.

This is my code thus far:

```
package libraycollection;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ViewCollectionController implements Initializable{

    @FXML Label collection_id_label;
    @FXML Label title_label;
    @FXML Label subject_label;
    @FXML Label isbn_label;
    @FXML Label description_label;
    @FXML ImageView imageView;

    //Edit
    TreeMap<Integer, Book> books = new TreeMap<Integer, Book>();

    public void nextBook(ActionEvent event){
        //This is a placeholder for Next button event.
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try{ getCollection();} catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        //Edit
        collection_id_label.setText(Integer.toString(books.size()));
        showBook();
    }

    //Edit
    public void getCollection() throws SQLException{

        String host = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:55556/librarycollection";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,"root","password");
        PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM book_collection WHERE user_id=?");
        stat.setInt(1,MainSelectorController.userID);

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){
            String title = rs.getString("book_title");
            String ISBN = rs.getString("isbn");
            String subject = rs.getString("subject");
            String description = rs.getString("description");
            String image = rs.getString("file");
            int book_id = rs.getInt("collection_id");

            Book book = new Book(title,ISBN, subject, description,image);
            books.put(book_id,book);
        }                      
    }

    //Edit
    public void showBook(){
       for(Map.Entry<Integer,Book> bookEntry : books.entrySet()){

         Integer bookId = bookEntry.getKey(); // this is your key - the id of the book
         Book book = bookEntry.getValue(); // this is the book with its properties

         //set the title to display
         title_label.setText(book.getTitle().toString());
        }
    }    
}
```

Is there a better way to get the data and only access 1 row each time a button is pressed?

**EDIT - Based on answer**
Would this be ideal:

```
public class Book {

    private String title;
    private String ISBN;
    private String description;
    Private String image;

    public Book(String title, String ISBN, String Subject, String description, String image){
        this.title = title;
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.Description = descritption;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need any more help with the code?

Comment: @Assafs I have tried many ways to iterate and extract the data, but must be doing something wrong...I have created a TreeMap<Integer, Book>.  Do I need a nested 'for each' loop, to traverse the TreeMap and then traverse the values of the book object?

Comment: Not exactly. Perhaps I can help if you update the question and add the new code you wrote?

Comment: Please read [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/243450) before attempting to ask more questions that are opinion based that invite argumentative discussion because they do not have a single agreed upon answer.

Comment: @Assafs I have annoted with //Edit for the parts that I have changed.  showBook() is where I would like to show the first book within the set which is triggered on loading of the stage.

Comment: Ok, that's easy enough - you just need to handle the book entry. I added a suggested edit to your code - once you approve it you can see the changes in the code that may help you.

Comment: @Assafs thank you very much. worked a treat.

Comment: Excellent! May I ask you to accept the answer? Just tick the grey check mark next to the answer and make it green :) also, if you like the answer, an up vote will be highly appreciated.

Comment: titles don't need *solved* in it. Marking an answer as accepted suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new class representing a Book, with the attributes you wish and the presentation you want.

You could decide to store the books as a Map books (using the isbn as the identifier, assuming it's unique per book).

Then you can efficiently check is a book exists, iterate over the list and present the next book easily - you could simply connect the press of the button with an iterator.next() on the Map entries, which will show you the next book.

Comment: I have added an edit, is this what you meant?

Comment: @ArcherGilly Yes, exactly. Now you can replace ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> with either Map<String,Book> or ArrayList<Book>. It would make your code much more manageable.